# Implementing custom key repository in dotnet core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To manage DataProtection for Cookies in dotnet core 1.1, one recommended approach was to implement IXmlRepository as a custom key storage provider and wired it up as follows in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IXmlRepository>(new MyCustomXmlRepository());
```

After upgrading to dotnet core 2.0, `GetAllElements()` is no longer called on my repository and `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always false.

The docs were always vague (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers) but still imply at the bottom that this approach is still valid.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement;

services.Configure<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
{
    options.XmlRepository = new MyCustomXmlRepository();
});
```

source: https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/251